# Why doesn't this string matches my regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex for capturing links in tags (the tags are given in a string without the angular brackets):

```
^a .*href=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"].*
```

and I have the following string:

```
a href="/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol" title="Hypertext Transfer Protocol"
```

And this string isn't captured by the regex. It seems fine to me, can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I does work for me, match group 1: `/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol`. Are you really applying it only on this string?

Comment: what language is this in? different languages have slightly different regex methods.

Comment: group 1 is captured correctly, but the entire regex is rejected for some reason.

Comment: Please post some more of your code.

Comment: [Don't use Regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: If group 1 was captured, the regex matched. Are you sure you are not trying to `find()` a match twice?

Comment: If you're using a Java Pattern to create a Matcher for your string make sure you call matches() first before checking the groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Java's `java.util.regex` package, `Matcher.match` only matches when the whole input sequence matches the regex. If you want to search a text inside another, use `matcher.find` instead. And of course, you have to reset the matcher between matches if you don't want the second `find` to start searching after the end of the first one.

Comment: I added `$` at the end. Thanks.